# Malware lab without virtual machines (Lubuntu as server/gateway)

Tags: server, windows, lubuntu, malware, gateway

I would like to set up a malware lab without virtual machines. 
On one laptop I have Windows 10, on the other Lubuntu, which will be used as a gateway/server. On the latter, I want an ethernet connection to the Internet and one wireless to connect host-only to Windows 10.

So, Windows should only be connected through host-only to Lubuntu, with no access to the internet as it will be the machine on which the dynamic malware analysis will happen.

Following this guide with virtual machines: https://medium.com/@xNymia/malware-analysis-first-steps-creating-your-lab-21b769fb2a64, I have tried to set up my environment in the same way with no success. 
I can't understand how to create the wireless host-only connection and setup Lubuntu as a server.
Do you have any suggestions on how to set up this lab?
Thank you.

Edit: sorry, the distribution is 19.10 64bit, LXQt.
The ip for the internet connection is 192.168.1.8, while for the wireless is 192.168.1.7 with gateway 192.168.1.8. The wireless ip 192.168.1.7 is setup on Windows 10 as gateway and DNS.

Comment: Firstly the age or release details of Lubuntu are useful; we don't know which desktop you are using (LXDE or LXQt) but also details of your networking stack where with release/age details we would have more clues.

Comment: I am not sure, but what about wireless bridge? Just do not give to its network access to the internet. I do not have such env to check if it is possible.

Comment: Edit: sorry, the distribution is 19.10 64bit, LXQt. The ip for the internet connection is 192.168.1.8, while for the wireless is 192.168.1.7 with gateway 192.168.1.8. The wireless ip 192.168.1.7 is setup on Windows 10 as gateway and DNS